# Obtaining a list of direct reports from the current user

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I have checked the two other threads and even used code from one but it never populates a list.  When I open up Active Directory Users and Computers and go to my Manager under Organization I see his list of direct reports.

What I am trying to do is gain access to that list through code.  Nothing I have found so far seems to work.

```
    public void GetDirectoryEntry(string adUserName)
    {
        DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://server.server.com");

        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
        ds.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(samaccountname=" + adUserName + "))";
        ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

        SearchResult rs = ds.FindOne();

        string distinguishedName = rs.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString();
        string department = rs.Properties["department"][0].ToString();
        string manager = rs.Properties["manager"][0].ToString();
        //string temp3 = rs.Properties["Reports"][0].ToString();

    }
```

I have tried using `Reports` and `directReports` and neither work both error out.

This method loads up the logged in user or any user I pass into it.  I can access all of their properties but I cannot seem to get access to their direct reports.

What am I missing?

Found the answer:

```
foreach (string objProperty in rs.Properties["DirectReports"])
            {
                isManager = true;
                string emp = objProperty.ToString();
                string[] setp = new string[1];
                setp[0] = "DC"; //If your users are in a OU use OU 

                emp = emp.Split(setp, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
                emp = emp.Replace("CN=", "");
                emp = emp.TrimEnd(',');
                emp = emp.Replace("\\, ", ", ");
                emp = emp.Split(',')[0];
                //emps.Add(emp);
            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
foreach (string objProperty in rs.Properties["DirectReports"])
            {
                isManager = true;
                string emp = objProperty.ToString();
                string[] setp = new string[1];
                setp[0] = "DC"; //If your users are in a OU use OU 

                emp = emp.Split(setp, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
                emp = emp.Replace("CN=", "");
                emp = emp.TrimEnd(',');
                emp = emp.Replace("\\, ", ", ");
                emp = emp.Split(',')[0];
                //emps.Add(emp);
            }
```